# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' when scrapping an array of URLs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

root = 'https://br.investing.com'
website = f'{root}/news/latest-news'

result = requests.get(website, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
content = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

box = soup.find('section', id='leftColumn')
links = [link['href'] for link in box.find_all('a', href=True)]

for link in links:
  result = requests.get(f'{root}/{link}', headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
  content = result.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

  box = soup.find('section', id='leftColumn')
  title = box.find('h1').get_text()

  with open('headlines.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(title)
```

I intend with this code scrape the URLs of news from a website, access each of these URLs, get its headers and write them on a text file. With this code, I'm just getting one header on the file and receiving `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`. What can be done about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, here: `title = box.find('h1').get_text()`, box is None (i.e NoneType)... which is why you're being told NoneType object has no attribute find

This is probably happening because at some point in the loop, this line: `box = soup.find('section', id='leftColumn')` returns None

If box returns None, the next line will throw an error.

You can fix this by checking if box is not None before calling find. So this:

```
box = soup.find('section', id='leftColumn')
title = box.find('h1').get_text()
```

will change to

```
box = soup.find('section', id='leftColumn')
if box is not None:
    title = box.find('h1').get_text()
```

EDIT:

The reason why you're seeing only one header is that you have `-w` here:  `with open('headlines.txt', 'w')`

`-w` will overwrite the file. I don't understand the contents but I would guess the output is the last header

**To fix**: replace `-w` with `-a`. it will add "title" to the file content. You can read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: I appreciate your help, but even with this change the error persists.

Comment: I tested the change on my laptop before posting the answer and it didn't give me any errors. Is it giving you the exact error you got when you made this post?

Comment: Sorry, I ended up expressing myself badly: there really is no error, but the final effect, which is just a headline in the file, persists.

Comment: my bad, I didn't fully understand your post. I've edited my answer. You'll probably need to add some \n if you want each header on a newline

Comment: Friendly reminder that if you run the code again, the code will still write to the pre-existing file so you'll get a bunch of repetitions in headlines.txt, so you need to delete the content of the file each time before running. You can add `open("headlines.txt", 'w').close()` just before your for loop to do this.